# Is it possible to manipulate Azure Sentinel Watchlists through Powershell/API

Tags: powershell, azure-sentinel

is it possible to administrate Azure Sentinel Watchlists through Powershell, like Rules with `Az.SecurityInsights`?

Aim is to keep Watchlist references in outer VCS for simpler manipulation, and sync it with Powershell to remote.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work on this seems to be coming, recently announced Microsoft Sentinel Repositories allows your VCS (GitHub or Azure DevOps) to sync to Sentinel:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/enable-continuous-deployment-natively-with-microsoft-sentinel/ba-p/2929413

With some small modifications, (edit the files in the `.sentinel/` folder you can deploy watchlist as well. at this moment only additions are processed through this trick, but real support might be coming.

Some more info: https://www.oppedijk.com/2021/11/18/Sentinel-CD-Repository.html

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer: No.
In a nutshell, I understand it's not implemented yet. [Only API endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/watchlist-with-rest-api).

It would be a waste of time if I coded the REST Powershell wrapper in parallel, assuming that target code for this would be Az.SecurityInsights.

I filed an feature request for this : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/15718 .

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/518881/is-it-possible-to-manipulate-azure-sentinel-watchl.html